# Estimate the moment of inertia of nucleus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

How do I estimate the moment of inertia of the rotating nucleus, $^{232}_{90}Th$, using the first order estimate assuming the nucleus does not change shape at high rotational angular momentum? Can you provide me the formula? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: What would you need to know to learn the angular momentum of a uniformly charged billiards ball? Can you find an approach that works with kind of information you can look up about a nucleus?

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to look at http://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/0104037 (Nucl.Phys. A694 (2001) 295-311) - they give figures for Th-224. For low deformation, the moment of enertia is about 5000 m fm^2, where m is the nucleon mass and fm is, I guess, Fermi (femtometer). I would think the moment of inertia of Th-232 should not be much different.